Type mismatching in parameters of function values
The following code generates a compile-time error at myFunctions.Add fn:
type IInterface = interface end

let myFunctions = ResizeArray<IInterface -> unit> ()

let add<'T when 'T :> IInterface> (fn: 'T -> unit) = myFunctions.Add fn

The error is "FS0001: Type mismatch. Excpeting a 'IInterface -> unit' but given a ''T -> unit'  The type 'IInterface' does not match the type ''T'"
This is puzzling to me for the obvious reason that I constrain 'T to IInterface.
There are no compile-time errors with the following code:
type IInterface = interface end

let myStuff = ResizeArray<IInterface> ()

let add<'T when 'T :> IInterface> (item: 'T) = myStuff.Add item

... so there is some property of function parameters that is incompatible with this approach.
What is that property, and is there a way to make my approach work?

F# has no implicit upcasting for object types.
So, the following compiles:
let add<'T when 'T :> IInterface> (fn: IInterface -> unit) = myFunctions.Add fn

(Note that your case is not covered by the language guide's statement "Upcasting is applied automatically when you pass arguments to methods on an object type". 'T -> unit :> IInterface -> unit is not an upcast. You would need upcasting earlier in the type checking process here, and that is not done in F#.)

The problem with this approach, Martin521, is that when I add (fun i -> ...), i is an IInterface, not whatever implements IInterface.  I could probably just cast i to whatever type it is that implements IInterface, but I was hoping I could avoid having to do that.

Yes, I understand that. In my experience, though, there are often different (more "functional") ways to structure a problem that don't lead to these issues. Difficult to say if there is such a way for your situation without seeing what you want to achieve on a larger scale.

Martin521, the larger context is that I have a core library that includes a function that registers special handler functions by type.  For example, for registerHandler<'f when 'f :> Fruit> (handler: 'f -> unit), if I have a function that I want to process Apple input, then I call registerHandler<Apple> (fun a -> ...).  Functions are added to a Dictionary with a Type key, so when the core library receives some input, it looks for the handler function by the type of the input.  Obviously, I can't predict pre-compilation what possible Fruit types the user will create for processing.

If you want exactly this way of registering the handler, then I guess it would need higher kinded types, which F# does not support. Can't you make the handler part of the interface?

Hey Martin521, funny you should ask.  I did actually consider making it a static method in the interface, and even wrote out the code.  Currently, I have it commented out, might revisit it at some point.  For now, just downcasting the interface type at runtime is what I've decided upon.

The property of function parameters that you are encountering is called "contravariance".
You can upcast an Apple to a Fruit (covariance), but you can't upcast an Apple -> unit to a Fruit -> unit (contravariance). If you could somehow perform this upcast, then you could invoke the resulting function with an Orange, which breaks type safety.
To avoid this problem, you can instead downcast the function argument at runtime:
let add<'T when 'T :> IInterface> (fn: 'T -> unit) =
    let f (x : IInterface) =
        fn (x :?> 'T)
    myFunctions.Add f

More info on covariance vs. contravariance.

Thanks Brian, down casting at runtime is precisely what I'm doing.  It works, I was just wondering about an alternative implementation, partially as an intellectual exercise.  I appreciate your insight.
